# Eliminate certain or repeated IP addresses

Tags: orangedox

Using OrangeDox, is there a way to prevent the count of views or downloads from the same person or IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Orangedox doesn't allow for this feature .. however we're looking to add in something to our Business account for our release slated early next year that would allow you to group previews & downloads by the IP address.